# What was the effect of the Video Game Crash of 1983 outside of North America?

Tags: history, game-consoles

The [Video Game Crash of 1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_crash_of_1983) is well known for the effect that it had on the video game console market in North America. A prime example is Atari [burying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_video_game_burial) thousands of unsold game cartridges in landfill. However the effect on other global markets is not as obvious to me.

What effect, if any, did the 1983 crash have on other game console markets, such as Asia, Europe, and South America?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89441/discussion-on-question-by-kaz-what-was-the-effect-of-the-video-game-crash-of-198).

Comment: Do you specifically mean "consoles", or any kind of video game hardware (i.e. home computers)?

Comment: "Consoles" in the first instance, but as the effects could extend to home computers, answers should be able to as well. For a made-up example: the withdrawal of console manufacturers from a market could have encouraged start-ups to make home computers instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> A prime example is Atari burying thousands of unsold game cartridges in landfill.

Well, that may have had its source with hubris over overestimated sales numbers (and licensing fees), in combination with less than desirable conversions regarding quality (Pac-Man) or story (Raiders of the Lost Ark) or combinations of both (ET).

> However the effect on other global markets is not as obvious to me.

As there was next to none.

> What effect, if any, did the 1983 crash have on other game console markets, such as Asia, Europe, and South America?

**In Europe** (*1) video consoles weren't as much hyped as in the US, and the market was far from saturation. In addition, US manufacturers didn't hold a major stake. European manufactured systems like [Saba Videoplay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_Channel_F), [Philips G7000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnavox_Odyssey%C2%B2#Europe) or [Interton VC4000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_4000) covered most of the market. Unlike US manufacturers as Atari or Coleco or Mattel, who tried to establish their systems as brands on their own, European systems were sold (in addition) under many brands (*2), usually by TV manufacturers who often adapted them to the feature interfaces of their TV sets (*3) or were even built into a TV set. Still, games could be exchanged, thus supplying all these 'different' systems with a reasonable game base to support purchase.

The transition to home computers, after 1980, happened in Europe well before market saturation, resulting in a smooth 'hand over', making already good home computer sales, when distributors in the US still tried to push ever more video games. It also enabled European companies like Thomson, Amstrad, Sinclair or Philips to establish major market shares.

The US downturn also had a major influence on dependencies of US companies (Atari, Commodore) by giving them a greater say in product development and support, as they became (for some time) the sole source of reliable income.

**In Japan** the situation developed mostly similarly, as here again the video game market was mostly supplied by local manufacturers and a smooth transition to early home computers happened without creating a bubble first.

---

*1 - Western Europe, at this time.

*2 - The Interton system gives a [great example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1292_Advanced_Programmable_Video_System#Released_versions) for this strategy in Europe

*3 - Usually also resulting in better picture and sound quality.

Answer (score 26):

The very same article you link says in [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Game_Crash) (rough translation):

> At the time of the North American crash the European market was strongly dominated by games for home computers, thus the crash had next to no consequences.

My memory completely agrees with that - There was no such thing as a *Video Game (console) hype*, so as such nothing that could crash - There was a *home computer hype* instead.

I was really surprised there actually is such an entry at all on German Wikipedia.

I do remember a very short (and small) wave of simple fixed-program "tennis/squash" video games consoles at the end of the '70s, but consoles like Atari VCS, Coleco, Mattel, Vectrex (if you consider that a Game Console) and even Philips/Magnavox (which was somehow European) never really got a foothold in European market in the '80s. Too expensive, too limited (to gaming), I guess. The home computer market, instead, was a real hype, starting with Sinclair computers in the early 1980s, and followed by Thomson, Acorn, and other European makers, later Commodore and Atari. As there was no console game bubble in Europe, no one heard it go bust.

Comment: Germany isn't different than the UK when it comes to the assumption of the importance of things happening in the US ... no matter how little relation they have in reality :)

Comment: @Raffzahn The problem is: There is no UK Wikipedia to refer to ;)

Comment: The article also clearly says "*European* market" - As far as I know, UK is still Europe (even if this might be disputable as well)

Comment: Tofro: Bloody Americanos, just taking over your language :)) But then again, why not adding a paragraph to the English page? After all, the UK was a leading force in the early 80s when it came to independant European developments.

Comment: No numbers for that but wasn't the US-crash the nail in the coffin for consoles like VCS in the European market as well? Ie: no hype but good sales for Atari that then dwindled for consoles?

Comment: @tofro I agree. I am British and I have no memory of any video games crash in 1983 or at any other time. In fact, this question is the first time I've ver heard of it.

Comment: There was certainly a home computer crash in the UK in 1984, but this was largely a problem for the hardware industry and not the software. The market was simply flooded with hundreds of incompatible computers, and by 1984 the craze for buying new computers was over as most people who wanted a computer had one by then, and there wasn't really a good compelling reason to upgrade for most people. But as far as I am aware this had little to no effect on software as people who had already got computers were still quite happy to buy new games for them!

Comment: @muzer This question is definitely not about home computers...

Comment: @tofro home computers are completely relevant because they're what most of Europe played video games on. And the crash in hardware therefore led to a period of relative stagnation in Europe when it came to the technology that games could take advantage of.

Comment: @muzer recommend you read the question again.

Comment: @tofro my point is that since the video game market as a whole was so tied to home computers during this time period in Europe, anything that was happening with home computers is relevant to the game console market. If people have powerful and cheap home computers with plentiful games for instance they're not going to buy a games console, but if their computer starts to look a bit long in the tooth and consoles are cheaper now (as happened later on) consoles are going to look more attractive.

Comment: @Muzer At least during the complete eighties, the home computer market in Europe was strong, very much stronger than any video console sales. The number of ZX Spectrum games alone will certainly be much higher than what was ever available for consoles of all vendors. And the home computer market stayed pretty strong during the advent of 16-bit machines like Atari ST and Amiga, until they were finally replaced by the home PC (which I consider the end of that hype). Only years later, when X-Box and Wii came up, consoles started to play a reasonable role in the European market

Comment: ...(I would even consider the Wii and the first X-Boxes the first consoles that reached considerable sales figures in Europe). But that was already in the new millennium and far later than the US crash we're talking about here.

Comment: @tofro I was certainly under the impression that the Super Nintendo and Mega Drive in the early 90s were the first consoles to find significant success in Europe. Computer gaming was still important of course but my feeling has always been that this is when consoles really *started* to eat away at the market share. And certainly I remember *lots* of people having a PlayStation or later a PS2.

Comment: The Mega Drive never even made it into Europe (other than the UK), the SNES may have had some success in mainland Europe. I'd rather assume the European market for consoles really only opened up when all you could have for a home computer was a boring old PC compatible.

Comment: _" consoles [...] never really got a foothold in European market in the 80ies"_ this could well be true in the UK, still in Germany SABA, Philips and Interton were quite ubiquitous in 1980. No department store, no TV/radio shop without - resulting in good sales. They succeeded after the Pong-alike craze during the second half of the 1970s, to be almost complete superseded by home computers as early as 1981/82, which in turn made the Japanese consoles of the mid 80s a lesser success than for example in the US. It wasn't until the end of the 1980s, when Sega's Megadrive made consoles big again.

Comment: @Raffzahn The Saba, Phillips, Interton I'd count to the "Pong-alikes". I wouldn't consider them "consoles".

Comment: @tofro Sure we talk about the same consoles? All three where quite like the Atari VCS (as well build to play Pong :)) in capabilites, build around microprocessors and ROM fed. In some aspects way more advanced than the Atari.

Comment: I've never seen one of those up close - but the choice of games apparently was much more limited than on the Atari

Comment: @tofro They are all what's now called [second generation systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_generation_of_video_game_consoles). For the number of games it might be a good idea to restrict this to the time in question. Up tp 1982 the VCS had ~55 cartridges, while the SABA had 26, Interton had 40 and Philips got ~70. I'd say all in the same range - and the VCS quite in the middle, in no way leading the list. Take look at the list of alternative brands they where sold under, you may recognize some.

Comment: @tofro _"The Mega Drive never even made it into Europe"_
That is patently incorrect, and I don’t know where you got that from.

Answer (score 12):

The Master System was the first really successful console in Europe; this was quite a while after 1983. Prior to that, video gaming was almost exclusively performed on home computers.

Prior to 1983 the big names in Europe were luminaries such as Sinclair, Commodore, Acorn and Thomson. All of those companies survived into 1984, and the market even grew from there — that's when Amstrad/Schneider launched the last of the really successful 8-bit computers.

If anything, 1982 and 1983 were boom years; Amstrad may have been a chronological outlier in achieving success but they were far from being an outlier in terms of launch date. Of the notable not-quites, the same period contains the Oric, which went on to a successful second-life in France as a decent budget micro with RGB SCART support; and the Enterprise which was a noble but late attempt at the same segment as Amstrad won of a perfected 8-bit. Less notable ones include the Memotech, the Tatung Einstein and the Camputers Lynx.

Further evidence can be found in the software houses: Rare and Argonaut were founded in 1982; Reflections and Rockstar North were founded in 1984.

So: existing companies survived, and capital continued to be available for new ventures.

One of the ironies of the whole period is that by the late '80s, the surviving American manufacturers — primarily Commodore and Atari — were primarily successful only in Europe. Commodore Europe outlived its parent, and it's no coincidence that the first post-Commodore owner of the Amiga IP was Escom, the German PC manufacturer. Initial shipments of the Atari Lynx and Jaguar both sold out in Europe, based on the reputation of the ST a few years earlier..Of the big five platforms for games as the '90s approached — the Spectrum, C64, CPC, ST and Amiga — three were American machines.

So: Europe saw no ill effects from the crash, even though it would be inaccurate to call it a freestanding ecosystem.

Comment: Crikey! I thought I knew of the majority of 80's 8-bit home computers but I have never heard of a Camputers Lynx, or a Mnemotech for that matter.

Comment: @user19862 well, it's actually a Memotech, clearly I was having a bad typing day. But the Lynx is cool — they used a 6845 CRTC but connected the cursor output as an interrupt signal, so you can set a raster interrupt to occur at any location on the visible screen. Sadly the machine got no real software support whatsoever though.

Comment: This answer touches on something that paralleled the US console crash but was, I think, unique to Western Europe in 1983~85:  a _home computer_ crash. There were multiple vendors pitching systems through 1983 and 1984, but many of these either failed to reach market, or failed to gain sufficient sales after launching, as the market had matured and buyers looked for machines with large software catalogues rather than good technical features.  The UK in particular had a string of startups making 8-bit micros, including Camputers and Enterprise (or Elan fame).

Answer (score 6):

The German market for video games and pinball machines had another crash at roughly the same time. From 1983 on, youth protection laws restricted those machines to locations where youth under age 18 had no admission.

That pretty much killed all the video games in public places and pushed the sales of home video game consoles and especially the Commodore C64 and Amiga computers.

Comment: These are arcade machines - not video consoles. Be careful when mixing German terms in Denglish isn't (US) English :))

Comment: @Raffzahn what, is video game Denglish for arcade game? That's a new one.

Comment: I'm afraid this answers a different question than the OP's

Comment: It's not the exact question, but it is related. At the least it clarifies that the growth in home computer (but not console?) sales in Germany was related to the restrictions on arcade machines, rather than the events in the US/Canada.

Comment: There was no such law in the UK - I grew up near Blackpool and spent a lot of time in the arcades.  But whilst there was some market for arcade conversions, porting those games to home computers (with varying degrees of success!), the arcades and home computers didn't really take market share from each other.  Arcade conversions were only ever a pale copy of the real thing.  And games which worked well on home computers with long play times (e.g. Manic Miner) were unsuited to coin-op play where you want to limit the amount of time per credit.

Comment: @Kaz Germany never fostered an arcade culture like in the US (or English sea resorts). In 1982, at the height of arcade machines in Germany, a 1.5m (3m with suburbs) city like Munich had about 10 arcade-like places (well, one was _pretty_ large). Making here a connection is rather far fetched. development (evolution?) isn't always and everywhere the same, even with seamingly equal results.